# Which terms are used for the digraph of the edges of a digraph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, directed-graphs

For any digraph $G = (V,E)$, consider the digraph $H = (E,F)$ with $F = \{ee' \in E \times E\ |\ \exists u,v,w \in V: e = uv \wedge e' = vw\}$, that is, the digraph $H$ whose nodes are the edges of the digraph $G$ and whose edges connect any two edges of $G$ which, together, form a directed path.

Which term is used in the literature for the digraph $H$ wrt. the digraph $G$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For undirected graphs this  is called the [line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph). In the link there is a short section on the *line digraph*.